# Return list or array from soap web service (cxf)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

Need get list or array from web service(cxf, and i use blueprint). WSLD, code, and stacktrace below. I tried to use Object[] but get similar error.

How fix this code?

```
public class Bean implements Service{

    public Pojo[] get() {
        Pojo p1 = new Pojo();
        Pojo p2 = new Pojo();
        p1.setName("1");
        p1.setAge("11");
        p2.setName("2");
        p2.setAge("22");
        return new Pojo[]{p1,p2};
    }
}
```

pojo:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Pojo {
    private String name;
    private String age;
//get's, setter's
}
```

blueprint:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="endPoint" address="http://localhost:9292/test" serviceClass="one.Service" />
<bean id="bean" class="one.Bean" />
<camelContext id="blueprintContext" trace="false" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route id="cxfRoute">
      <from uri="cxf:bean:endPoint"/>
      <log message="${header.operationName}"/>
      <recipientList>
          <simple>direct:${header.operationName}</simple>
      </recipientList>
  </route>
  <route id="get">
      <from uri="direct:get"/>
      <bean method="get" ref="bean"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

After camel:run and send request, i get this stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Part {http://one/}return should be of type [Lone.Pojo;, not one.Pojo
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.checkPart(DataWriterImpl.java:273)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:205)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:114)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:242)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:78)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:355)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:319)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1088)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1024)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handleAsync(Server.java:410)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:519)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you post WSDL here?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I am not sure if I understood the question, but your stacktrace says that the program is expecting a "Lone.Pojo" for some reason not the "one.Pojo" like in the blueprint- this is why you get IllegalArgumentException maybe. Not sure if that will help, maybe you misspelled something.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an answer, and so tried, and it worked. I do not know how much it is correct.

```
public class Xtype {
    Pojo[] currs;

    public Pojo[] getCurrs() {
        return currs;
    }

    public void setCurrs(Pojo[] currs) {
        this.currs = currs;
    }
}
```

&&

```
public interface CurrService {
    Xtype date() throws Exception;
}
```